# How to handle card's button OnClick event in GridView? Best practice

Tags: android, button, gridview, onclick, android-cardview

I'm trying to find the best solution to handle `OnClick` event, which generates by my card's button (see the picture bellow) within `GridView`.

[image: my card and button on it]

So as you can see, I have just a normal `GridView` with cells made of my custom Card.

I just initialize `GridView` and it's adapter:

```
mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
mAdapter = new ImageTopicsAdapter(..blah blah blah..);
mGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

As you probably know I can easily handle `OnClick` events generated by `GridView`. But it will work only if I click on the card itself:

```
mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(..blah blah blah..);
```

I want to build something similar to this (see code bellow), so I can easily "implement" my `Activity` to handle my card's button `OnClick` event:

```
mGrid.setOnItemButtonClickListener(..blah blah blah..);
```

**What is the best (clean\easy\elegant) way to do this?**

Any help is truly appreciated. Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like nobody knows how to do this. So I found solution myself with help of @Dimitar G. and @Konstantin Kiriushyn. Thank you, guys.

**1)** I will create my own custom `CardView` using Compound View system, which will be pretty simple: `LinearLayout` + `ImageView` + `TextView` + `Button`.

```
public class TopicCardView extends LinearLayout {

   private ImageView mImage;
   private Button mButtonMenu;
   private TextView mTitle;

   public TopicCardView (Context context) {
      initializeViews(context);
   }

   private void initializeViews(Context context) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      inflater.inflate(R.layout.topic_card_view, this);
   }

   private void setTitle(...) {
      ...
   }

   private void setImage(...) {
      ...
   }

   private void setMenuClickListener(...) {
      ...
   }

   // and so on...
}
```

**2)** Then I will create method called `createListOfGridCardsFromDB(...)` in `Activity\Fragment`. It will generate list (`LinkedList`) of my custom `CardView`s (and it will also set titles\images and listeners to `CardView`s).

**3)** And then I will pass this generated `LinkedList` of my `CardView`s to `GridViewAdapter`.

**This system makes able to use only one Adapter for all my card-grids in app. It also  makes able to do nothing with clicks, interfaces, listeners and stuff in Adapter**.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to dispatch to your activity, I would recommend exposing a method in the activity and call it directly from your click listener. The shortest (and cleanest from my perspective):

- in your Adapter, say `ArrayAdapter`

  - define to listen for clicks (to avoid multitude of anonymous listener instances)
  - dispatch a call directly to your activity (since every view context is an activity)
  - `context` above can be treated as your `ApplicationActivity` **only** if you didn't manually provide some other context, say application context

    ```
    private final MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // inflate your card then get a reference to your button
            View card = ....;
            card.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID).setOnClickListener(this);
            return card;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ApplicationActivity activity = (ApplicationActivity) view.getContext();
            if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
                applicationActivity.onCardButtonClick();
            }
        }
    }

    // in your ApplicationActivity
    public final class ApplicationActivity extends Activity {
        ...

        public void onCardButtonClick() {
            // deal with your click
        }
    }
    ```

There are other, `textbook` options (setting a listener, or activity in your view creation and so forth) but I avoid them since they don't solve absolutely anything.

They just add more dust in your code.

Any `View` context defined properly points to the activity (since it is a context too) which holds all view structure. This way you can access your activity quick and relatively easy.

BTW Event bus is not a good option since event buses are great for one-to-many relations (one dispatcher, many listeners) but add more complexity when used intensively for one-to-one calls (dispatcher-listener)

**Addition for the comment**

You can tweak a little the code and rather using the adapter, you can dispatch directly from your cell. In other words rather using the adapter as a delegate, create an anonymous listener and then reach and call the activity directly from your card button click:

```
public final MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate your card then get a reference to your button
        View card = ....;
        card.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ApplicationActivity activity = (ApplicationActivity) view.getContext();
                if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing() && !activity.isDestroyed()) {
                    applicationActivity.onCardButtonClick();
                }
            }
        });
        return card;
    }
}
```

**Addition for the comment - Compound View**

To encapsulate all cell logic, you can create a custom view from scratch or use a [compound view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound). The example below is using a compound view:

```
public class ApplicationActivity extends Activity {
    ....

    public void onCardButtonClick(Cell cell) {
        // do whatever you want with the model/view
    }
}

// ViewModel instances are used in your adapter
public final class ViewModel {
    public final String description;
    public final String title;

    public ViewModel(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title != null ? title.trim() : "";
        this.description = description != null ? description.trim() : "";
    }
}

public final class Cell extends LinearLayout {
    private View button;
    private ViewModel model;

    // ViewModel is data model and is the list of items in your adapter
    public void update(ViewModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        // update your card with your model
    }

    public ViewModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ApplicationActivity activity = (ApplicationActivity) view.getContext();
                if (model != null && activity != null && !activity.isFinishing() && !activity.isDestroyed() {
                    activity.onCardButtonClick(Cell.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

// then your adapter `getView()` needs to inflate/create your compound view and return it
public final MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final List<ViewModel> items;

    public MyAdapter() {
        // update your models from outside or create on the fly, etc.
        this.items = ...;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {        
            // inflate - say it is a layout file 'cell.xml'
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell);
        }

        ((Cell) convertView).update(items.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! Please see my comment to Konstantin Kiriushyn's solution. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @AlexMomotov Adapter code updated to reach the activity without a need to use the adapter as a delegate

Answer (score 1):

Adapter should handle this. Generally your Adapter should have method like setOnOptionsClickListener(OnOptionsClickListener listener) assuming that we are talking about ellipsis button.

So in your Activity/Fragment you use following code

```
public interface OnOptionsClickListener {
      void onOptionsClicked(View view, PictureItem item);
}


mAdapter= new MyGridAdapter();
mAdapter.setOnOptionsClickListener(new OnOptionsClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view, PictureItem item) {
            //process click
       }
});
```

And following inside Adapter

```
public void setOnOptionsClickListener(OnOptionsClickListener l) {
    mOnOptionsClickListener = l;
}

findViewById(R.id.btn_options).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void OnClick(View view) {
        mOnOptionsClickListener.onOptionsClicked(view, currentPictureItem);
    }
});
```

**Please notice.** You need to declare interface only if you need to have extra parameters in `OnClick()` method (for example `currentPictureItem` to get image url or item id). Otherwise, you can use just OnClickListener.

**Edit** 
So here is explanation. `Adapter` serves like a View-provider for your `GridView`. It creates views and it configure it basic state. That's why all click listeners should be set in `Adapter` during views initializing. Moreover, we don't want to have a messy `Activity` with nested `Adapter`, but we want to have Adapter as a separate class. This is the reason you will usually need to create additional interface in order to have an access to `currentItem` object to extract data from.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply.

It's clear enough for me. I'm using this solution right now. But do you think it is the best way? Such technique breaks the encapsulation rule a little bit. Yeah, `Adapter` serves like a view-provider for `GridView`. Only view-provider. That's it. I feel that it is wrong to make able `Adapter` to handle views clicks (i.e. make it `implements View.OnClickListener`). Maybe there's another option? Maybe we should build our own `GridView` class with such capability? What about Google apps? How do they do that?

Comment: In this case Adapter didn't **handle** view clicks. It just **listen** to click event **and delegate** it to Activity. And all logic occurs in activity.

Comment: Ok, I see. My mistake. Sorry. :)
But the main idea is the same. Is it possible to make Adapter to do nothing with clicks and stuff? Is it possible to leave Adapter alone and do something else without it?

Comment: I think that is almost impossible. Because you have **getView()** method where you, for example, call _View view = inflate(R.layout.item)_ at top and _return view;_ at very bottom. So you should tie click listeners between.

Comment: @AlexMomotov I thought your question is not using adapter for click dispatch which is in my **Addition for the comment**. There it uses inline click and cast/call the activity from the anonymous button click listener. You have another option which is define a custom view (compound or from scratch) and deal with clicks in it. Please look at **Addition for the comment - compound view**

Comment: @DimitarG., I see. Thank you! Your answer helped me to find solution.